# Align fields in column in VF page

Tags: visualforce, stylesheets

This is my code:

```
<apex:outputPanel title="Subscription List Front" id="subscriptions_list_front">
        <apex:pageBlock rendered="{!show}" id="selectFront">
            <apex:commandButton id="ViewAll" value="View All" onclick="viewAll()" />   
            <br/><br/>                
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{! subscriptions_front }" var="sub">
                <apex:column headerValue="Subscription #" headerClass="headerStyle">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!InvokeShow}" rerender="subscriptions_list_front, subscriptions_list_filtered,subscriptions_list_table,subscriptions_list_map" >
                        <apex:param name="DeviceId" value="{!sub.DeviceId__c }" assignTo="{!DeviceId}"/>
                        <apex:param name="ContractNumber" value="{!sub.SBQQ__ContractNumber__c }" assignTo="{!ContractNumber}" />
                        {! sub.Name }
                    </apex:actionSupport>
                </apex:column>
```

```
<style>
    .headerRow .headerStyle{background: #e6ecf2;color: rgb(81, 79, 77);font-weight: bold;}
    tr.dataRow.even {background-color: rgb(250, 250, 249);}
</style>
```

I am trying to align my column values to the right, but nothing works

Answer (score 1):

There is a rule in CSS where the most specific style wins and SFDC is annoyingly specific with their styles so either you have to be more specific or you can use the !important flag to make yours take priority.

Using styleClass:

```
<style>
    .rightAlign {text-align:right !important;}
</style>

<apex:column headerValue="Subscription #" headerClass="headerStyle" styleCLass="rightAlign">
```

Or Add it as an inline style:

```
<apex:column style="text-align:right !important;">
```

**Note:** Inline styles usually beat out stylesheets, unless the stylesheet has !important. I don't think sfdc uses !important (thankfully) so you may not need it but it can't hurt.

Alternatively SFDC automatically adds "dataCell" and "dataRow" classes to the cells and rows so you can try something like this:

```
.dataCell {text-align:right !important;}
```

But that will be every cell in the table as opposed to a single column.

Lastly, they have even/odd classes as well so something like:

```
.dataRow.odd {background-color:green;}
```

Will also help you style your tables.

**Example:**

```
<apex:page controller="testPageController">
    <style>
    .alignRight {
        text-align:right !important;    
    }
    </style>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="c">
            <apex:column value="{!c.AccountId}" styleClass="alignRight"/>
            <apex:repeat value="{!contactFields}" var="f">
                <apex:column value="{!c[f]}" />
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class testPageController {
    public List<Contact> contacts {get; set;}

    public List<String> contactFields {
        get {
            if (contactFields == null) {
                contactFields = new List<String>();

                for (Schema.FieldSetMember fsm : SObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.testFieldSet.getFields()) {
                    contactFields.add(fsm.getFieldPath());
                }
            }

            return contactFields;
        }

        private set;
    }

    public String queryFieldString {
        get {
            if (queryFieldString == null) {
                queryFieldString = '';

                for (String s : contactFields) {
                    queryFieldString += ',' + s;
                }
            }

            return queryFieldString;
        }

        private set;
    }

    public testPageController() {
        String query = 'SELECT Id' + queryFieldString + ' FROM Contact';
        system.debug(query);
        this.contacts = database.query(query);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, whenever I do the first approach with styleClass, it doesn't really do anything. The .datacell style aligns all datacells and .dataRow.odd the odd ones. So, from 10 columns I now have, I would like to align the text in just one of them. Is this possible in this setup?

Comment: @mirantii I've updated my example with a working page/controller showing how style class works so I know it will work. Also your comment doesn't say anything about the inline style option I provided, have you tried that?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I have tried the inline option and the headerClass (styleClass) options as well. The thing is, the code you have provided is a little bit quite different than the one I am using, so there should be a css classes clash somehow as you suggested before

Comment: Your code doesn't show any of your css, can you update your question with the CSS

Comment: Updated with the css I was having so far. I can also send you a link to the code I already tried, but it is basically the same idea. I think this is mainly due to the fact that the <apex:column> has and <apex:param> within and also a <apex:pageBlockTable> and <apex:outputPanel> as parents.

Comment: Can you preview the page, right click on a cell in the table that you want right aligned and then copy the entire TD element HTML and provide that as well? I don't think that the contents of the cell matter but the provided HTML might reveal something.